# Class function with a pointer parameter not saving to vector

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I wasn't exactly sure how to title this, but basically, I have this class function that is designed to add a new ability to the vector of abilities in the class.

```
//Part of class Unit
public:
vector <Ability*>  myAbilities;
void AddAbility(Ability * ability)
{
    myAbilities.push_back(ability);
    cout<<"Ability added"<<endl;
    cout<<ability->GetName()<<endl;
    ability = NULL;
    delete ability;

}
```

I am pretty sure that the pointer in the parameter basically vanishes when the function is done and when I try to output the abilities name within the main function, it doesn't exist.  I prefer the use of this function to be:

```
AddAbility(new Fireball());
```

Fireball being a child class of Ability.

How might I add a new ability to the vector of pointers to the class Ability through this function?  I'm pretty sure doing it by reference is pointless and there is the chance I just forgot something basic, but I can't seem to pinpoint it.

Comment: Why do you nullify `ability` before deleting it?

Comment: *I am pretty sure that the pointer in the parameter basically vanishes when the function is done* -- the pointer gets copied to the vector, so there is no loss of data in that regard. There must be something else you are doing to come to the conclusion that the object "doesn't exist".

Answer (score 2):

If you are compiling with C++11, consider using [shared pointers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/), and let the system handle memory management:

*per Casper Von B's comment below*, `unique_ptr` seems to be a better fit for your particular situation (updated):

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Ability>> myAbilities;

void AddAbility(Ability * ability)
{
    auto ptr = std::unique_ptr<Ability>(ability);
    myAbilities.push_back(std::move(ptr));
    cout << "Ability added" << endl;
    cout << ability->GetName() << endl;
}
```

Alternatively, you could just let `Ability` do all of the constructing/destructing. In general, the class which creates the object should be the class which destroys it.

Additionally, this:

```
ability = NULL;
delete ability;
```

.. is likely backwards. When you *do perform cleanup*, be sure to reverse that order:

```
delete ability;
ability = NULL;
```

Comment: In this case, ownership seems to be exclusive thus unique_ptr would be a better fit.

Comment: It is fine to call delete on a null pointer. The standard is clear in stating that `delete a_null_ptr` is not to cause runtime errors. What will most likely happen in his code however is a memory leak.

Comment: Actually `free` and the `delete` operator allow null, it's defined in the standard as a no-op. You would of course leak memory in most cases if you nullify something before deleting it.

Additionally if we are giving advice on modern practices, `nullptr` in-place of `null`. I've edited accordingly if it gets accepted.

Comment: My mistake, I was mixing up `delete`ing `null` and double `delete`s :)

Comment: Okay, I have not really been able to find anything on passing by pointer, but how I see it right now, ability becomes a new Fireball and when you have the new instance, you are suppose to clean it when done and since it is a parameter it will be gone when the function finishes. So why would I not delete it at the end of the function?

Comment: @Uulamock but you're not done with it at the end of the function - you're done doing whatever you want to do with it for now, but that doesn't mean that *you're done with the data that pointer points to* (since you are saving it to the vector for *something* I assume)! You're passing a pointer to a location in memory; that's not a *new instance* just because it's a parameter. This is why you don't delete it yet.

Comment: @MrDuk It gave me some insight for sure, but I actually found out...that I was forgetting to actually output the name of the Ability correctly....I really hate myself when I do that. I spent a good week trying to figure out what was wrong. But you guys did show me my problem with delete and NULL and I think I can say I understand that now. So thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You delete the ability (so the pointer does not point to anything anymore). In the ability vector, you have this pointer that now doesn't point to anything.
So, don't nullify and delete the pointer. The Ability destruction should be done by the Ability destructor.

And yes, the pointer gets copied in vector, as something like `0x455ff930`, but remember that when you delete it, the location of memory `0x455ff930` (that was what the pointer was pointing to) is not associated with ability anymore.